# React.memo is not available when working with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use React.memo like so:

`const Node: React.memo<Props> = props => {`

But i'm getting an error saying:

`Namespace '../ui/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"' has no exported member 'memo'.`

But I can see the Memo function within index.d.ts:

```
function memo<P extends object>(
    Component: SFC<P>,
    propsAreEqual?: (prevProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>, nextProps: Readonly<PropsWithChildren<P>>) => boolean
): NamedExoticComponent<P>;

function memo<T extends ComponentType<any>>(
    Component: T,
    propsAreEqual?: (prevProps: Readonly<ComponentProps<T>>, nextProps: Readonly<ComponentProps<T>>) => boolean
): MemoExoticComponent<T>;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: that function is not exported.. there is e.g. `type MemoExoticComponent` in [@types/react/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L771)...

Comment: People are using it though, for example: https://medium.com/memebox-tech/be-more-functional-with-react-memo-typescript-2a0e4f4833ad

Comment: they use `React.memo<Type>(...)` as a function call, not as a type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `memo` is not a type declaration. You have your syntax messed up a little bit

```
const Node: React.FC<Props> = React.memo(props => {
  return(
      <div>
        memoized
      </div>
  )
})
```

Note that `React.FC` is a declaration of a functional component. Since you're wrapping it in a `memo`, you *might* need to change the type. But personally, I have not needed to.

Comment: React.FC is not needed, simply pass your type to memo: `React.memo<Props>(props => {...`